# Range Slider inside Action Sheet | Ionic 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic2

I'm making an app with Ionic 2 and need to know if Range sliders could be placed inside Action sheets.

Already googled it and looked in the docs but nothing on this topic was found.

https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/action-sheet/ActionSheetController/
ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/range/Range/

So far I've tried this:

```
{ text: `<div class="item range range-balanced">
             <input type="range" name="volume" min="0" max="100" value="35">
         </div>` }
```

but with no results. Here I left a CodePen example: https://codepen.io/louibazz/pen/GNbpMV/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to write custom Action sheet to active slides in this.

Comment: did you manage to create it ? I'd be interested into implementing this in my app too